# After all these years, is there any way to change wifi settings with iPhone app?

Tags: ios, wifi

I understand that it's not possible to do that, but recetenly I found an app named Skybell which designed for the doorbell camera device, it seems that can do it. Any one has any idea how it works? Maybe iOS8 opened some related APIs for use?

Here are 2 videos of skybell

1. Original function, need enduser change the wifi settings.

   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASHpyE829E8
2. New, it seems that Skybell app did everything, using bluetooth? I don't think so, there should be a way to do it.

   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rPX-S_CP6-E

Comment: I would guess that they are using the Wireless Accessory Config (WAC) feature - this is covered by the Apple MFi program

Comment: I don't think so, it seems that wireless share need enduser's permission, it will show a message box to let you press the allow button, but in the video,  there is no message box showed.

Comment: Looking at the video again my guess would be Bluetooth as you need to enter the WIFi password into the app

Comment: Yes, bluetooth could be the solution, I will try to get one to see how it works.